# How To make Google Form plugin appear on Homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Chameleon Theme from eleganttheme.com for my site project. See at onthegoventuresng.com and I want to display a form below the 3 blurbs content areas on the homepage.

I spoke with the customer support, they said that's beyond the support they can provide for the theme. I was advised to seek a 3rd party help for the theme customization.

Meanwhile, I know it's the theme's homepage file home.php

I installed Google Form plugin with the intent that the form should display below the content areas on the homepage.

Pls how do I go about this any code to insert will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you know where to add the code in home.php, you can try adding this:

`<?php do_shortcode('[wpgform id="xx"]'); ?>`

Replace xx with your form id, and make sure you're adding that outside of any other php tags.

This will run the shortcode to display your form through the do_shortcode function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Thanks for you reply and willingness to help, I inserted the php code to above the last code line in the home.php, it didn't display
</div> <!-- end #content-area -->

<?php do_shortcode('[wpgform id="121"]'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: Sorry, try `<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgform id="121"]'); ?> `